# How to sort each line in two dimensional array in Java. From txt file

Tags: java

How to sort each line in a two-dimensional array in Java. From text file.
I have to

```
 public class Average {

    static int[][] myDouble = new int[10][12];
    static int x = 0, y = 0;
    static int strDouble;

    public Average() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StudentIdAverage.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split("\\s+");

                for (String str : values) {
                    strDouble = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    myDouble[x][y] = strDouble;
                    y = y + 1;
                }
                x = x + 1;
                y = 0; 
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Average arr = new Average();
        int[][] residuescores = arr.myDouble;
        for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myDouble[i].length; ++j) {

                System.out.print(Average.myDouble[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

/*
    45  72  90  50  67  63  81  71  55  56  80  74/n
    55  54  79  72  75  68/n
    51  88  79  72/n
    98  52  52  53  50  92  67  99  92  50  61  91/n
    94  48  53  92  97/n
    97  69  77  74  68  54  87  74  54  83  58  69/n
    75  49  87  61  66  53  79  48  96  60/n
    58  71  51  73  53  75  93  81  45  69  78  65/n
    50  88  78  81  99  61  97  70  87  80  69/n
    91  89  97  80  93  82  92  49  52  69  96  61
     */

can any body help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) 
    Arrays.sort(myDouble[i]);
```

Comment: @johnjohn Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you, so that the community knows that the question is solved.